# How can I select a point without selecting its reflected side

Tags: selection-tools

I have on the mirror modifier and I only need to select a point one side without deleting the mirror modifier.  How does one accomplish such a task?

Comment: if you select the vertice of one side it will necessarily select the vertice of the other side, but you should explain why you're trying to do

Comment: If your question is about breaking the symmetry for that vertex you mention then you need to apply Mirror modifier first and proceed to edits you'd like to do with that vertex

Answer (score 2):

Your question conflicts with the *Mirror Modifier* purpose. It is used to mirror your model in a given direction to reduce workflow or give symmetry to your model, you cannot select a vertex of the mirrored part.

Simply apply the *Mirror Modifier* to your model, and then you can edit one side and it will not affect the other, because you applied the modifier and each side it's independent.

[image]